# How to remove shapes from a vector path?

Tags: android, xml, vector, icons

I was looking for an torch on and torch off icon in Android Studio's vector asset search for a camera app. I couldn't find either, but I found a similar icon (vector xml) called as **highlight**.

[image]

I have used it as a placeholder for **torch on**. I wanted to remove the three rectangles and increase the height of the torch holder to cover the remaining height for **torch off** icon. Is it possible to achieve this? If yes...then how could one achieve it...if not, then what alternative could I go with?

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector
    android:height="24dp"
    android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:width="24dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <path
        android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
        android:pathData="M6,14l3,3v5h6v-5l3,-3V9H6V14zM11,2h2v3h-2V2zM3.5,5.88l1.41,-1.41l2.12,2.12L5.62,8L3.5,5.88zM16.96,6.59l2.12,-2.12l1.41,1.41L18.38,8L16.96,6.59z"/>

</vector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the vector you asked for

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:tint="#FFFFFF"
android:viewportWidth="24"
android:viewportHeight="24">
<path
    android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
    android:pathData="M6,14l3,3v7h6v-7l3,-3V9H6V14zM11,1" />
```